# Linear vector space with a subspace with finite number of elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there a (linear) vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ which contains a non-zero subspace comprised of a finite number of vectors?

Comment: No, there cannot be such a thing over an infinite field.

Comment: No. Over an infinite field, a non-zero  subspace contains a dimension $1$ subspace, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: In simpler terms, is your argument equivalent the fact that for whatever subspace we choose ($dim \ge 1$), we have an infinite number of scalars to multiply by, and, hence, an infinite number of vectors in the subspace, or is there something more subtle to it?